# Adding items in bulk to Azure DevOps using tf commandline

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfvc, azure-repos

ers,

One of our products depends on third party software that we receive monthly updates for. The received software contains a variety of files and binaries in a complex folder structure containing around 100-150K files. We need to add new items to our version control so we can include it in our build pipeline.

We run over the entire folder structure via a Powershell Script and execute "`tf.exe add file`" for each (relevant) file. This currently takes around 14 hours. We've made it multi threaded but that doesn't seem to affect the processing time a whole lot. "`tf.exe add`"-commands just take their time and don't run concurrent from what we can tell.

```
TF.exe add fileOne.dll
TF.exe add fileTwo.png
```

We also tried optimizing it handle multiple files in one command

```
TF.exe add fileOne.dll fileTwo.png
```

But haven't been able to get this to work. According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/f9yw4ea0%28v%3dvs.100%29#examples) you can specify multiple files

> itemspec - Specifies the scope of the items to add. You can specify more than one
>   itemspec argument

But TF.exe errors out on us

> TF.exe: C:\workfolder\fileOne.dll fileTwo.png : no file matches.

To my questions:

1. Why isn't it letting us add multiple files/itemspecs with "tf.exe add"?
2. Is there a more efficient way to make this process, bulk adding files to DevOps, faster?

Comment: Instead of adding the files to source code every time, why don't you instead convert the 3rd party stuff into a NuGet package and then have it add it's contents dynamically to the workspace before compile-time like any other NuGet package.  Thus you never have to version control it since it's 3rd party stuff.  That's what I did with RightAngle.  No need to check-in the whole Solarc library into source control, just convert it into a NuGet package.

Answer (score 1):

The itemspec is a glob format [and explained here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/use-team-foundation-version-control-commands?view=azure-devops#itemspec).

You can use multiple item specs, but each must be prepended with the path (or be rooted in the current directory), so either:

```
tf vc add C:\workfolder\fileOne.dll C:\workfolder\fileTwo.png
```

Or

```
c:
cd workfolder
tf vc add fileOne.dll filetwo.dll
tf vc add .\fileOne.dll .\filetwo.dll                         | equivalent of the above
```

But if what you're trying to do is adding all files in a specific folder when needed, then the wildcard option combined with `/recursive` is your friend:

```
tf vc add c:\workfolder\* /recursive
```

To further speed up the process, you can switch to a Local Workspace, in that case the `tf vc add` command won't need to talk to the server to prepend the change, it is only registered locally. Then the checkin command will be able to send the whole batch of changed files in bulk to the server.

You can switch the workspace with the following command:

```
tf vc workspace /location:local
```